# Check if Spotlight is during volume indexing on OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm looking for some method to determine whether Spotlight is currently indexing any volume.
In my app I'm using NSMetadataQuery to search files but they might not be found if Spotlight didn't finish indexing.
The app is sandboxed so I cannot use mdutil.

Any insights or alternative approaches to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!